# typescript and Nodejs this in controller returning undefined

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I've searched long and hard all over stackoverflow and the web for a solution to this but couldn't find anything that was similar to my problem, could be since I'm new to typescript so I'm still not fully comfortable with it.

I'm trying to access `this` in my controller and passing in a dependency through the constructor.

Below is my `pushNotificationRoute.ts` file where I inject the `apn.Provider` to the Controller.

```
import { Request, Response, Application } from "express";
import { PushController } from "../controllers/push-controller";
import { Routes } from  "./routes-interface";
import *  as apn from "apn";
import { options } from "../configurations/options";

export class PushNotificationRoute implements Routes {

    public pushController: PushController
    public apnProvider: apn.Provider

    constructor() {
        this.apnProvider = new apn.Provider(options);
        this.pushController = new PushController(this.apnProvider);
    }

    routes(app: Application) {
        console.log("routes called -----")
        console.log(this.pushController);


        app.route('/notification')
        .get( this.pushController.getNotifications);

        app.route('/notification/send')
        .get(this.pushController.sendNotification);

    }
}
```

then in the  controller I do the following

```
import {Request, Response } from 'express';
import *  as apn from 'apn';

export class PushController {

    public apnProvider: apn.Provider

    constructor(apnProvier: apn.Provider) {
        this.apnProvider = apnProvier
        console.log("new apn provider intialised ", this.apnProvider);
    }

    public getNotifications(req: Request, res: Response) {
        res.json({
            message: "get notificatoins"
        })
    }

    public sendNotification(req: Request, res: Response) {
        console.log("sendNotification controller function ", this.apnProvider); //crashes here when I call this.apnProvider

        let deviceToken = "898Y89F95BC283D2D933376E477AD38D9435552434WEQE633ADC4C58BED9B61"
        var note = new apn.Notification();

        note.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; // Expires 1 hour from now.
        note.badge = 3;
        note.sound = "ping.aiff";
        note.alert = "What are you doing now?";
        note.payload = {'messageFrom': 'John Appleseed'};
        note.topic = "com.mangafruit.compendium";
        console.log("sendNotification controller function ", this.apnProvider);

        this.apnProvider.send(note, deviceToken).then( (result) => {
            console.log("First notification Inshallah this will benifit my family & i")      
            res.json({
                message: "notification send successfully :D"
            })
        });

    }
}
```

The server crashes when I access `this` in the `PushController().sendNotification()` function

Thanks

Comment: `this.pushController.sendNotification` is passed as a callback. It needs to be bound to proper `this`

Comment: how can I bound it? I tried making `var self = this` in the constructor from the other answer but couldnt get that to work since its local to the constructor .

Comment: See dupe question, it covers everything you need to know about the subject. `var self` is ES5 solution, it isn't applicable to classes. There should be `this.method = this.method.bind(this)` in constructor.